# Naive Bayes: Heterogeneous CPDs for observation variables

Tags: binary, classification, probability, naivebayes

I am using a naives bayes model for binary classification using a combination of discrete and continous variables. My question is, can I use a different conditional probability distribution (CPD) functions for continuous and discrete observation variables ?
For example, I use gaussian CPD for continous and some deterministic CPD for the discrete variables ?

Thank you

Comment: Yes. It's not assumed in the derivation of the formula that the cpd's be all the same. As for combining continuous and discrete, a conventional abuse of notation is to pretend that probability densities are probabilities; this is justified by pretending there is a dx next to each p(x | C).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is normal to mix continuous and discrete variables within the same model.  Consider the following example.

Suppose I have two random variables:

- T - the temperature today
- D - the day of the week

Note T is continuous and D is discrete.  Suppose I want to predict whether John will go to the beach, represented by the binary variable B.  Then I could set up my inference as follows, assuming T and D are conditionally independent given B.

```
           p(T|B) • p(D|B) • p(B)
p(B|T,D) = ━━━━━━━━━━━━ ∝ p(T|B) • p(D|B) • p(B)
                p(T) • p(D)
```

p(T|B) could be a Gaussian distribution, p(D|B) could be  a discrete distribution, and p(B) could be a discrete prior on how often John goes to the beach.

Comment: Thank you Timothy. That answers my question!!